# What is the equivalence class $a/0$ equal to?

Tags: commutative-algebra, equivalence-relations, localization

Let $D$ be a domain. Let $D^{*}$ be the set of non-zero elements of $D$. We define a relation $\sim$ on $D\times D^{*}$ as follows: $(a, b)\sim(c, d)$ if and only if $ad=bs$. It is easily checked that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. We denote the equivalence classes with respect to this relation as $a/b$. Let $F$ denote the quotient set.

I wonder to know what is the equivalence class $a/0$ equal to?
If $a/0=b/c$, then $ac=0$ and since $D$ is a domain, then $a=0$.

What about the equivalence class $0/0$?

May you help me, please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

$a/0$ doesn't have a class, since $(a,0)$ is not an element of $D \times D^*$. (unless $D$ is the zero ring)

For a variation on this construction where one *does* have $a/0$, see the [projective line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_line). If you want  $0/0$ too, see the [wheel of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory)

---

One can consider the [localization of a ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring) with respect to more general sets than $D^*$. If you include $0$ in the set of elements you invert, then the resulting ring will be the zero ring.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, we cannot say  that $a/0=0/0$ even though $a 0 = 0 0= 0$.

Answer (score 1):

There are no such equivalence classes. Only elements in $D\times D^*$ have equivalence classes, by definition. So no element whose second component is zero can have an equivalent class. It is further instructive to see what will happen if you attempt a similar construction starting with the set $D\times D$.